# How can I write Rails routes to identify particular parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have a route like the following.

```
match "/shop/:city(/:filter1)(/:filter2)(/:filter3/)(:filter4)"  =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter
```

What I need is after :city, it can be filter1, filter2 etc.. Else

filter1/filter2 together.

So I need routes like

```
match "/shop/:city/:filter1" =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter

match "/shop/:city/:filter2" => "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter


match "/shop/:city/:filter1/:filter2" =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter

match "/shop/:city/:filter1/:filter3"  =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter
```

But the problem here is when I am sending filter2 or filter3 only then it is taken as filter1.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: It will always be taken in order `(/:filter1)(/:filter2)(/:filter3/)(:filter4)`. Better to implement on `filter` like `match "/shop/filter/:city"  =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter` so that it takes any number of filters through parameters as `/shop/filter/:city?filter1=value1&filter2=value2&filter3=value3&filter4=value4`

Comment: Thanks Amit. But I really don't want to use ?filter1value1&filter2=value2&filter3=value3&filter4=value4. The data will be between in the url slashes. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: `"/shop/:city/:filter1/:filter3"  =>  "shop#filter"` means If you want only `filter1` and `filter3` but not `filter2`, then its not possible, because the arguments will always be taken in order. What's the difference between these different filters?

Comment: Its from different category. Sometimes some category will not be there. Like Eletronics part, Eletronics parts items etc. So I need the url like City/TV/Tv-Stand. If the user needs only stand I need it like City/Tv-Stand, if he needs only TV then City/TV. If he needs both then City/Tv/Tv-Stand. Here I can't understand, user is requesting TV or TV Stand or Both. Is there anyway in rails that it takes not in the order ? like filter1 or filter2 or filter3 ?

Comment: No, the problem with this route is even if you say `City/Tv-Stand` then also it will take `Tv-Stand` as filter1 (where as you expected it to be filter2) . I hope you are understanding what I mean?

Comment: You have to change your route to get it working like `/shop/filter/:city?filter1=value1&filter2=value2&filter3=value3&filter4=value4`, so that you can access value of these filters through the parameter name

Comment: Yes thats right. So is there any other way to write this route to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult problem n-depth filter.

I recommend you like this

in routes.rb

```
match "/shop/:city/:filter" =>  "shop#one_depth_filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_one_depth_filter
match "/shop/:city/:filter/:subfilter" =>  "shop#two_depth_filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_two_depth_filter
```

in shop_controller.rb

```
def one_depth_filter
    redirect_to root_path unless params[:filter] != 'filter1' && params[:filter] != 'filter2'
end

def two_depth_filter ... end # same logic like one_depth_filter
```

additional comment.

in routes.rb

```
match "/shop/:city/*filter" =>  "shop#filter", :method => :post, :as => :shop_filter
```

in shop_controller.rb

```
def filter
    filters = params[:filter].split("/")
    # implement
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can't use redirect. The filters are from different category. Sometimes some category will not be there. Like Eletronics part, Eletronics parts items etc. So I need the url like City/TV/Tv-Stand. If the user needs only stand I need it like City/Tv-Stand, if he needs only TV then City/TV. If he needs both then City/Tv/Tv-Stand. Here I can't understand, the user is requesting TV or TV Stand or Both. Is there anyway in rails that it takes not in the order ? like filter1 or filter2 or filter3 ?

Comment: added additional comments. it covers any depth filter. good luck